# can't make PUT PATCH and DELETE request in node.js/express?

Tags: node.js, express

My delete request is not working,what i am trying to achive is on click of a button i want to make a delete request?

> the HTML5 spec only allows GET or POST, unfortunately so i cannot use data-method or method anything else

```
<a href="/posts/delete/"   method="delete" type="submit" >delete</a>
```

handling request :

```
app.delete('/posts/delete',(req,res)=>{
res.send('delete');
})
```

but it is returning:

```
Cannot GET /posts/delete/
```

istead of

```
delete
```

> Is there any way to do this without Libraries and Ajax Call?
>
> When i make request with get it works fine can someone also explains
>   why we need delete request when it can just be handeled by get ?
>
> Also patch and put ,looks similar to post request what's the difference with example please ?

for further clarification [this is rest-api](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) but this works only with postman when i am using in browser  Cannot GET /posts/delete/ is rendering for all the requests

Comment: are you sure the attribute name is `method` or `data-method`?

Comment: i tried both not working

Comment: the HTML5 spec only allows GET or POST, unfortunately. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method. If you need any other verb, you will need to use JavaScript (to prevent the default form action, and then manually contact your server with the correct verb).

Comment: thanks but how should i handle the request ? AJAX